# On Error Resume Next does not catch SQL server error in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a piece of vbscript code that I am runnning in QTP

```
objRecordSet.Open "select regn_code from region where regn_code  ='" & rCode & "'",objConnection 
    On Error Resume Next
     If Err.Number <> 0  Then
             Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"Error in " & module,"" & ErrObject.Description
         End If

     On error goto 0
```

rCode is a numeric value in Database. When rCode value is supplied as varchar in QTP e.g 'er', SQL server throws me an error 
Invalid column name 'er' which stops my QTP AUT.

I want to know why is 'On Error Resume Next'  unable to handle this error. Any suggestions will help. As a workaround, I am simply trying to skip this sql query if rCode is non-numeric.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How can `rCode` be a numeric value when you're using it in a string comparison (`regn_code = '...'`)? Besides, building SQL queries by concatenation is strongly discouraged. Use a [parameterized query](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190) instead.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Sorry Ansgar, what I meant to write was it gives error - "Cannot convert varchar to numeric' when value supplies is 'er' but if value supplied is '1', it works.

Comment: That's probably because the DBMS implicitly casts strings with numeric values from varchar to numeric. If you need to compare numeric values, don't put them between quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, your 'workaround' - not executing the SQL if you haven't got a decent parameter - is the correct solution.

If you want to disable normal error catching for the .Open line, the OERN has to go before it:

```
On Error Resume Next
objRecordSet.Open "select regn_code from region where regn_code  ='" & rCode & "'",objConnection 
...
```